# JXLS Dynamic Grid throws null NestedNullException

Tags: jxl, jxls

I'm using this documentation example as reference to create dynamic grid by specifying the headers names and the needed properties from certain object.
http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/dynamic_grid.html

But in my case `Employee` object has nested properties "adres.housenumber"

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private Date birthDate;
    private BigDecimal payment;
    private BigDecimal bonus;
    private Adres adres;
    // constructors and getters/setters
    .....
}

public class Adres {
   private String housenumber;
}
```

It works fine if all employees have an `adres` with a `housenumber`, if employee has adres, then I got below exception:

> Caused by: org.apache.commons.beanutils.NestedNullException: Null property value for 'adres.housenumber' on bean class 'class Employee'
>
> at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:795) ~[commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
>   at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:884) ~[commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
>   at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:464) ~[commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
>   at org.jxls.command.GridCommand.processBody(GridCommand.java:185) ~[jxls-2.3.0.jar:?]
>   at org.jxls.command.GridCommand.applyAt(GridCommand.java:137) ~[jxls-2.3.0.jar:?]
>   at org.jxls.area.XlsArea.applyAt(XlsArea.java:168) ~[jxls-2.3.0.jar:?]
>   at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.processGridTemplate(JxlsHelper.java:156) ~[jxls-2.3.0.jar:?]

This employee data is retrieved from the database so I have no access to modify it before passing to the exporting to Excel.

Any idea/help please?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is due to the GridCommand when it tries to evaluate the property of a property when there is a null property set. So Apache PropertyUtils (used by GridCommand) throws an Exception.

In your example attribute adres in your Employee class is null so the evaluation of adres.housenumber throws an exception.

In order to avoid this behavior you can use an Iterable object instead of your bean. In this way GridCommand doesn't evaluate props but just asks to the Iterable object its values.

I've done this project to show to you how it works.
https://github.com/LucianoZu/jxlsnofault

You can use IterableWrapper class to just wrap Employee and avoid the exception.